# Oracle read nth column using a cursor

Tags: oracle, cursor

can i read column data in a cursor giving the index of the column?

thanks...

---

From the questioner's comments :
"I need to create a generic procedure which will read a table or view (name of the view or table is the argument of the proc) and encrypt the data in the column and then will write the encrypted data to a OS file. "

Comment: What do you mean , like "select 7 from emp" to get the 7th column?  If so the answer is "no".

Comment: No, is there any method like cursor.col_data(2) ? where 2 is the index of the second columns.I dont know the name of the column how can i read it?

Comment: Please give us an example of your code ...

Comment: You don't need to know the name of the column when fetching it from the cursor.  You can just "fetch mycursor into var1, var2".  Maybe you should provide (in your question) some more background into what it is you are trying to do.

Comment: there is not related code yet, i need to create a generic procedure which will read a table or view (name of the view or table is the argument of the proc) and encrypt the data in the column and then will write the encrypted data to a OS file. I guess i need something like reflection =)

Comment: Then you must determine the name of the needed column. For that you can use the view "user_tab_columns". In that view every column for every table in the schema is stored. The "column_id" shows the order of the columns in a table.
Example:

<code>select table_name, column_name, data_type, column_id from user_tab_columns;</code>

Comment: Using DBMS_SQL you can write a procedure that takes a table name, executes the SQL "select * from <table name>".  You can then dynamically determine the columns, get the data and write it wherever.  Is that what you need?

Comment: In the relational model of data there is no such thing as the "nth" column. It ain't a spreadsheet :)

Comment: Well, using DBA_TAB_COLUMNS.COLUMN_ID will give you the nth column in the order that the columns where added to the table. You could use DBMS_SQL to generate a query based on the table/column metadata.

Comment: thank you for answers. do DBA_TAB_COLUMNS include VIEW columns? I implemented the procedure using DBMS_SQL i think the right solution is using DBMS_SQL

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should give you a head start.
Just plug in your encryption code for the column number you want.
I've used VARCHAR everywhere. If you want dates and numbers (or more exotic datatypes), then you'll need to handle the conversion.

```
create or replace function qry_dump
  (p_tab_name in varchar2, p_rownum in number default 5)
return tab_char_4000 AUTHID CURRENT_USER pipelined is
  v_line      varchar2(2000);
  v_col_cnt   INTEGER;
  v_ind       NUMBER;
  rec_tab     dbms_sql.desc_tab;
  v_tab       dbms_sql.varchar2a;
  v_temp      VARCHAR2(32000);
  v_cursor    NUMBER;
  v_clause    VARCHAR2(200);
begin
  --
  -- Initial values
  --  v_ind := 1;
  v_temp := 'select * from '||p_tab_name||' where rownum <= '||nvl(p_rownum,5);
  --
  -- Identify the columns in the target and build the new query
  --
  v_cursor := dbms_sql.open_cursor;
  dbms_sql.parse(v_cursor, v_temp, dbms_sql.native);
  dbms_sql.describe_columns(v_cursor, v_col_cnt, rec_tab);
  --
  FOR v_pos in 1..rec_tab.LAST LOOP
    v_line := rec_tab(v_pos).col_name;
    dbms_sql.define_column( v_cursor, v_pos, v_line, 2000);
  END LOOP;
  v_ind := dbms_sql.execute( v_cursor );
  --
  -- Fetch each row from the result set
  --
  LOOP
    v_ind := DBMS_SQL.FETCH_ROWS( v_cursor );
    EXIT WHEN v_ind = 0;
    pipe row( '=============================================================');
    --
    -- Go through each column and display it
    --
    FOR v_col_seq IN 1 .. rec_tab.COUNT LOOP
      -- Get the value
      dbms_sql.column_value( v_cursor, v_col_seq, v_line );
      pipe row( rpad(rec_tab(v_col_seq).col_name,35)||'>'||v_line);
    END LOOP;
  END LOOP;
  return;
end qry_dump;
/

select * from table(qry_dump('DEPT',3));
```

Comment: hi thanks for your answer, your code quite similar to mine. But i have a problem about sizes of the data retrieved. I defined columns as '' and gave a length of 4096. But what if columns is CLOB? I guess your code also exlodes at that point. When i try to change the columns_definition data type to CLOB i got some error like 'Expected number got date' any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Additional answer for CLOBs.
Simpler code as I've hardcoded the table/column_name. 
The main difference is that v_line is now a CLOB and that the final parameter (length) is dropped from the call to DEFINE_COLUMN since it is only relevant to VARCHAR2.

If you are dealing in very large CLOBs (eg 10s or 100s MB plus), then I can foresee other challenges (memory, performance...).

```
create or replace function clob_dump
return tab_char_4000 AUTHID CURRENT_USER pipelined is
  v_line      clob;
  v_col_cnt   INTEGER;
  v_ind       NUMBER;
  rec_tab     dbms_sql.desc_tab;
  v_cursor    NUMBER;
begin
  --
  -- Identify the columns in the target and build the new query
  --
  v_cursor := dbms_sql.open_cursor;
  dbms_sql.parse(v_cursor, 'select sql_fulltext from gm_c where rownum <= 5', dbms_sql.native);
  dbms_sql.describe_columns(v_cursor, v_col_cnt, rec_tab);
  --
  FOR v_pos in 1..rec_tab.LAST LOOP
    v_line := rec_tab(v_pos).col_name;
    dbms_sql.define_column( v_cursor, v_pos, v_line);
  END LOOP;
  v_ind := dbms_sql.execute( v_cursor );
  --
  -- Fetch each row from the result set
  --
  LOOP
    v_ind := DBMS_SQL.FETCH_ROWS( v_cursor );
    EXIT WHEN v_ind = 0;
    pipe row( '=============================================================');
    --
    -- Go through each column and display it
    --
    FOR v_col_seq IN 1 .. rec_tab.COUNT LOOP
      -- Get the value
      dbms_sql.column_value( v_cursor, v_col_seq, v_line );
      pipe row( rpad(rec_tab(v_col_seq).col_name,35)||'>'||substr(v_line,1,100));
    END LOOP;
  END LOOP;
  return;
end clob_dump;
/

select * from table(clob_dump);
```